# Adding content to page messes up with the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I've used [this](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/) generator to produce a gradient background I like. With that I managed to create the following looking CSS code. It fades between different flavors of blue.

```
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2BD0FF 0%, #09ADF1 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2BD0FF 0%, #09ADF1 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2BD0FF 0%, #09ADF1 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #2BD0FF), color-stop(1, #09ADF1));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2BD0FF 0%, #09ADF1 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2BD0FF 0%, #09ADF1 100%);
```

I've pasted that in the body section of my CSS code. It looks smooth but when I add content using [the code I posted in another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840154/simultaneous-setintervals-only-first-one-running/15842251?noredirect=1#15842251) it makes the background striped.

Here's a picture demonstrating the effect happening. The picture is actually a screenshot of the issue which happens when I add `&nbsp;` in the `body`. What happens with the clouds (for clouds, see the link above) is similar but the stripes are wider.

[image]

My HTML page contains some other elements in the `body` but removing them don't affect the situation. I've included jQuery 1.9.1 in the `head` section and my code which is exactly the same as in the discussion linked earlier.

What causes this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-repeat: no-repeat`. This should solve the problem.

Comment: No luck with that one. [This is what happens.](http://imageshack.us/f/838/sieppaaa.png/). The blue is part of the gradient, the white circle is part of a cloud and the remaining white is part of the background. Using `no-repeat` caused the background to end there.

Comment: Is the element you are applying the gradient to filling up the entire page? If not, make is so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to albertxing, I found the right keyword and used Google to find the solution. It seems this topic has already been covered in another question.

[CSS Background Gradient Repeat Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427331/css-background-gradient-repeat-issue)